# PostgreSQL No space left Error for a self-join query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query which produces matrix of products which are bought together means has the same `ticket_id`. table `calc_base` has 500 millions rows (43gb). This query is run on a machine with 122gb RAM, 16 CPU, 600 SSD. `CREATE INDEX ON calc_base(TICKET_ID);`

```
  create  table calc_tmp as
    select
        a.product_id x_product_id,
        a.product_desc x_product_desc,
        b.product_id y_product_id,
        b.product_desc y_product_desc,
        a.units x_units,
        b.units y_units,
        a.sales x_sales,
        b.sales y_sales,
        a.flag x_flag,
        b.flag y_flag
    from calc_base a
        inner join calc_base b on a.ticket_id = b.ticket_id;
```

All other queries working fine just this query after 45 minutes threw this error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not extend file "base/12407/18990.223": No space left on device
  Hint: Check free disk space.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2455)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2155)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:288)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:430)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:356)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:168)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:116)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:83)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:83)
    at dbAnalysis.config.NamedParamStatement.executeQuery(NamedParamStatement.java:31)
    at dbAnalysis.dao.DbAccess.profile(DbAccess.java:61)
    at dbAnalysis.Benchmark.perform(Benchmark.java:63)
    at dbAnalysis.controller.ConsoleApplication.main(ConsoleApplication.java:95)
```

Is it related to the temporary files size? 
I want to know why this kind of behaviour happens in PostgreSQL. 
I appreciate any suggestion to solve this problem.

Comment: Disk space done ran out when you were running your query. **Hint: Check free disk space.**. Remember when doing a self-join you're computing the cross product. This can be exponentially huge for large amounts of data.

Comment: I checked always I have plenty of free space. just this query cause this error!

Comment: I bet you have zero when this error happens. Postgres doesn't just spew nonsense. Your join probably produces a bazillion rows.

Comment: @tadman: there is no cross join involved here. It is a regular inner join. A self join is **not** a "cross product"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's running out of space, so something crazy's going on here. That was my first instinct. Maybe it's wrong.

Comment: The statement creates a _new_ table and the free space on your harddisk is not enough to hold all the data that should be stored in that table

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to get from such query, and provide some details on your table structure, at least: is ticket_id a primary key?

Comment: I added more information. so how can I know how much space does this query needs ?

Comment: @Arezoo: The fact that it failed while writing the file `18990.223` means that it had already filled 223 1GB segments when it failed. Maybe if you explain what you're actually trying to calculate then someone could suggest a more efficient method.

Answer (score 3):

You clearly have lots of duplicates in `ticket_id`.  To see the number of rows generated, you can run the following query:

```
select sum(cnt * cnt)
from (select cb.ticket_id, count(*) as cnt
      from calc_base cb
      group by cb.ticket_id
     ) cb;
```

Actually, I realized that the above would count `NULL`, whereas your query would filter it out.  Add `where cb.ticket_id is not null` to the subquery if the value can be `NULL`.

Comment: thanks, yes there are duplicates in `ticket_id`. Do I need to change any parameters in postgresql.conf in order to have better performance?

Comment: `count()` already returns `bigint`. If it's not enough, `sum(1::numeric)` could be used.